Subbundle for left invariant vector field on Lie group
Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$ its Lie algebra. A section on tangent bundle $TG$ is a vector field on $G$. I want to know that if there exist a subbundle $L(G)$ of tangentbundle, such that $\Gamma(L(G))$ (section of $L(G)$) is equal to the set of all left invariant vector field? I try to define a vector space at $g\in G$ as
$$
L(G)_g:=\{L_{*,g}v\mid v\in\mathfrak{g}\}
$$
and then construct $L(G):=\coprod_{g\in G}L(G)_g$. But is it really a vector bundle? I think it's essential to show two things: 1: $L(G)$ is a smooth manifold, 2: the map
$$
L(G)\to G\times \mathbb{R}^n, L_{*,g}(\sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i)\mapsto (g, (e_1,...,e_n))
$$
where $e_1,...,e_n$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$, is a diffeomorphism.
Is my method correct, how should I proceed? Or is there any simpler way to describe such a bundle?

The set of left invariant vector fields is completely parameterized by $T_e G$, and if you want a sheaf whose sections are left invariant vector fields, you are going to need to take a locally constant sheaf.  Your construction is essentially just constructing the tangent bundle by saying every tangent vector is part of a unique left-invariant vector field.

What you are trying to construct here doesn't really make sense. Left-invariant vector fields span the whole tangent space and your construction $L(G)$ is just $TG$.
Consider the following, if you take a left-invariant vector field $X$ and rescale it different amounts at different points you get a vector field $fX$ (for some nonconstant function $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$) that is no longer left-invariant but this would span the same line bundle as $X$ does. So there can be no subbundle consisting entirely of left-invariant vector fields (except trivially the $0$ bundle).

My question originally comes from the fact that if a vector bundle $\pi:E\to B$ has a global frame $z_1,...,z_n$, then one can define a connection as $\nabla_X(\sum_{k=1}^n \beta_kz_k):=\sum_{k=1}^n X(\beta_k)z_k$. I know on tangent bundle of Lie group there is a global frame for all left invariant vector fields and I want to define a connection in this way. But when there is no such subbundle, how can such a connection be defined?

@GaoMinghao where does a subbundle come into that? The frame is of the tangent bundle not some hypothetical subbundle. The fact that left-invariant vector fields span the tangent bundle allows you to choose this frame in a neat left-invariant way. I think you might need to check you understand what a subbundle is

Sorry I'm clear now, I have thought that only left invariant vector fields can be expressed as linear combination of some $z_1,...,z_n\in\Gamma(TG)$. Now I know that in fact any $X\in\Gamma(TG)$ can.
